# plot a binomial negative with alpha and beta parameters in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, probability, bayesian

How can I plot a Negative Binomial with parameters alpha=1.71 and beta=1.05

I've traied

```
barplot(table(rnbinom(10000,1.71,1.05))/10000)
```

Comment: you're going to have to specify what parameterization you're using (e.g. how do your alpha/beta parameters correspond to the ones used on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) ?)

Comment: And then I use something like   
x <- 0:30  ; plot(x, dnbinom(x, size=4, prob=0.3), pch=16)

Comment: If you have a package loaded that has that function, you should include the library call in the code.

Comment: Is this the parameterization you're talking about?  http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?t=50208

Comment: @Ben Bolker With a shape parameter α = k and an inverse scale parameter β = 1/θ, called a rate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you might be trying to plot Beta negative binomial, as alpha nad beta are usually used to denote alpha and beta for beta distribution.
I.e. you can use rbnbinom() from extraDist package.

```
hist(rbnbinom(1000, size = 1, alpha = 1.71, beta = 1.05), breaks = 100)
```